# running ansible as bash script from PHP

Tags: php, bash, ansible

I'm running a bash script that includes ansible playbooks:

```php
$bash = 'bash /var/www/.ansible/tmp/script-copy.sh'
$out = shell_exec($bash);
```

But when I'm running it I get following error:
`ERROR! the playbook: ip-prefixlist.yml could not be found`

Where does php run ansible? It can't find playbook.

Comment: Add the `pwd` command to your script to determine the current working directory. If you have relative paths in your script, they will be interpreted starting from that directory. You might need to `cd` to another directory, or use absolute paths.